# how to customise sales email in magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I am designing the transactional emails for my webshop and have created new templates with custom design. However, for the sales emails I am not able to customize all content. Where can I customize the shipping description, shipping address and the order items grid?
It is called by the following 3:

```
{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

Comment: what is magento version?

Comment: The version is 1.9.0.1. There is no transactional email templates associated with the design theme we are using.

Comment: the email templates are taken from app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales for English store

Comment: The content I am trying to cuztomize is not available through the templates. See my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

From Admin side of Magento,

**Go to system->Transactional Email**

and create your own Template and set it as you wish.

Comment: The content I am trying to cuztomize is not available through the templates. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to customize email templates.

1. Go to `Admin > Sytem > Transactional Email > Load template`
   Customize it as per your requirement and save it and assign it in configuration who you are editing.
2. Directly from `app\locale\en_US\template\email`

Comment: The content I am trying to cuztomize is not available through the templates. See my updated question.

Comment: Hi
this are the core part functions. You have to purchase any third party extension to customize email template as per your design. I am saying for third party extension because to change core part is not good practise. :)